# How to correct this syntax error: invalid character in identifier

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import json
from threading import Timer
import scrapy
import hashlib
import time
import numpy as np
import self as self

NONCE_LIMIT = 400000000000

zeros = 14

random_scores = np.arange(stop= 4000000000,start=1000000000,step=1)
print("random_scores",random_scores)

def mining(block_number, transactions, previous_hash):
# this line shows error 
    for nonce in range(1000000000, NONCE_LIMIT):
        base_text = str(block_number) + transactions + previous_hash + str(nonce)
        hash_find = hashlib.sha256(base_text.encode()).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Your code has shown has no syntax error  .but what is `import self as self` ?

Comment: Whatever error you are seeing is likely in `self.py`.

Comment: Will you please guide me how to sort this error.that is self.py but I see error on my program on line number 19.     for nonce in range(1000000000, NONCE_LIMIT):

Comment: @azro kindly look into the line number 19. When I try to run my program it shows syntax error. Let me post full program

Comment: The code you show here parses just fine if you comment out `import self as self`. Whatever error you are seeing isn't reproduced here.

Comment: @chepner I need full assistance that am new to python. Where to post full program

Comment: You don't need to post the full program. Start by posting the *exact* traceback you get.

Comment: @chepner when I try to run my program it shows error at line number 19 as syntax error: invalid character in identifier. (I.e for nonce in range line)

Comment: Please update your **question** with the **text** of the full error traceback.

Comment: The error message should include the character it thinks is invalid. Stop describing the error message to us, and copy it into the question.

Comment: I tried to add a line and now it shows default.py line 18 error

Comment: There's probably a non-printing character in that line. Check it with a hex editor.